# How to emulate a http.server for faster unittest in python3?

Tags: python, unit-testing, http, request, python-3.3

I am trying to emulate a http server on localhost for faster testing.

ex:

```
import my_module

class RequestsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # ...
        html = 'hello, world'
        my_server = MyServer(html, 8888)
        my_server.run()
        ...

    def test_my_module_request_phrase(self):
        response = my_module.get_phrase('http://localhost:8888/')
        self.assertEqual(response, 'hello, world')
```

Is something like this possible using python 3?

Comment: What web framework are you using ?

Comment: I am not using any web framework. Just pure python3 on a linux box

Comment: Alright, just asking because it is usually a bad idea to start up a server in a unit test (makes it slow and unreliable) and many web frameworks offer a 'fake' client that emulates a server. Sorry :)

Comment: Thank you. So, is it a bad idea? How would it be if I am using Django?

Comment: Depends on what `my_server.run()` does. If it blocks, then `setUp()` will not return, and your test(s) won't be executed.

Comment: Are you trying to test the client, the server, or an integration scenario?  It kind of looks like an integration scenario, in which case you can't really mock out the server and have a legitimate test.  If you are doing a client test, you can monkey patch whatever http library you are using to stub out the actual network communication and just return canned responses to the client.  If you are testing the server, unless you are actually trying to test the network stack, you can just mock out the request object and feed canned ones in to your models and other code.

Comment: Possibly related: [Integration testing: Start a blocking server during `unittest.setUp` before testing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392132/integration-testing-start-a-blocking-server-during-unittest-setup-before-test)

Comment: In django, you would use [django.test.client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client). But as sr2222 said, it depends on what you are testing.

Comment: I just wanted to test the response of a request without the need of internet, but if I understand what you mean. I shouldn't be testing this kind of request on unittests, right?

Comment: Unless you have some middleware or something you are trying to test as well, you should be able to get away with mocking out the request object and feeding it in to your models, then validating you get the appropriate response object.  You should still at least do some cursory end to end integration testing though, to sanity check the full stack.

Answer (score 3):

> I just wanted to test the response of a request without the need of internet (...)

No problem. You can run your test http server on the same host you run your tests. If you run it in the same process your tests are being run in (which is the case when using unittest and running test server from within `setUp()` method) then the server has to be run in a separate thread so that it doesn't block your tests. You can take a look how it's done in urllib3 [here](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/dummyserver/testcase.py#L14).

Comment: That link is stale, this seems to be the actual upstream repo: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/dummyserver/testcase.py

Answer (score 2):

First, consider the following aspects:

- See if it is possible to pull I/O (such as web requests) to the outer layers of your program (google for Clean Architecture). This will make testing much simpler.
- Make sure you have integration tests in place which test your application in its final context including live web services.

If you are still looking for a tool to easily unit test the remaining web I/O, please consider using the libraries [httpretty](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty) or [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses). With these tools, it is easily possible to specify fake responses including header fields, return codes, and more. The resulting test code will be much cleaner and shorter than what you would write with Python mock alone (or a custom real web server you run concurrently in some other thread).